# CSS: Is it possible to remove a child of a Grid element from flow?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'd like to have the div "Another line" on a new line
And I'd like to avoid absolute positioning

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Mogget24/pen/oNwgZJN)

```
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div class="another-line">another line</div>
</div>
```

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 16px;
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.another-line {} // ???
```

***Edit:*** the number of elements prior to "another-line" is not fixed

Comment: `.another-line { grid-row: 3; }`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this

```
.another-line {
  grid-column-start:1;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 16px;
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.another-line {
  grid-column-start:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div class="another-line">another line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yes that's it! It didn't work for me as I was trying to set the grid-row-start property

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 16px;
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box1 {
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 2;
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-row-end: 2;
}
.box2 {
   grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-column-end: 3;
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-row-end: 2;
}
.box3 {
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 2;
   grid-row-start: 2;
   grid-row-end: 3;
}
.box4 {
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 2;
   grid-row-start: 3;
   grid-row-end: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box1">1</div>
  <div class="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box3">3</div>
  <div class="box4">another line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mmh this doesn't work as the number of "boxes" is not fixed